# How do I show a non-interactive "preview" of another part of the same web page without duplicating all the contained HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with a large, dynamic, user-configurable graphical element (SVG) as the focus and some HTML elements to frame it. I want to show a small, hovering, non-interactive preview of this main graphic-and-frame off to the side when the user scrolls it at least partially out of the viewport.

Is there a way to specify that an element should display the same exact content as some other given element? This second element does not need to be interactive, so it functions like a dynamic image showing another part of the same page. I imagine something a bit like those minimap sidebars you see in Sublime Text or VS Code.

I have considered manually synchronizing the HTML content, but this is error-prone and can increase state management complexity considerably since I can no longer keep things simple by coupling the single view to the underlying state. It also won't (easily) capture any style changes influenced by :active, :hover, etc., though doing so is not a hard requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "real" SVG element, but putting the SVG in two places won't work in this case. I've added some more detail to the question to explain why.

Comment: Paint the required html elements and the svg onto a canvas?

Comment: It looks like the `element()` CSS function does more or less what I want, but it's been considered experimental (and Firefox-only) for years. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element

Comment: Yes, but I guess to be practical you need to do this for yourself for now, eg. with HTML2Canvas or similar.